# Control HTML element's style on scroll with window.scrollY

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change font-size and margin-bottom of a div element when scrolling using window.addEventListener('scroll', function(){}); and window.scrollY value. But I don't want it to change forever if I don't stop scrolling. I only want to reduce the font-size from 256px to about 192px and margin-bottom to about 128px. Can you guys please show me how to control it? Sorry I just started JS for couple days.
Below is the part of my code.

```js
let brownie = document.getElementById('backgroundBrownie');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let value = window.scrollY;
  brownie.style.fontSize = 256 - value / 4 + 'px';
  brownie.style.marginBottom = value + 'px';

})
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="backgroundText" id="backgroundBrownie">
    Brownie
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check the value you have computed with an `if` and `else if` statement.

At present, this seems quite jerky. I suspect your algorithm needs refining.

```js
let brownie = document.getElementById('backgroundBrownie');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let value = window.scrollY;
  
  let fontSize = 256 - value / 4;
  if(fontSize < 192)
    fontSize = 192;
  else if(fontSize > 256)
    fontSize = 256;
    
  let marginBottom = value;
  if(marginBottom > 128)
    marginBottom = 128;
    
  brownie.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
  brownie.style.marginBottom = marginBottom + 'px';

})
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="backgroundText" id="backgroundBrownie">
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
    Brownie<br />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using while loop at first like: while(value <= 128 + 'px'){brownie.style.marginBottom = value + 'px';}. But the code didn't run. Anyway, your solution helps me solved this problem. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
        let value = window.scrollY;
        let fontSize = 256 - value/4;
        brownie.style.fontSize = fontSize < 192 ?  '192px' : fontSize + 'px';
        let marginBottom = value;
        brownie.style.marginBottom = marginBottom < 128 ?  '128px' : marginBottom + 'px';
```

These inline ternary operators check if the value is less than your limit. If it is, it the property is set to the limit. If not, it uses the computed value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your code solved the issue easily. But I found it:
brownie.style.marginBottom = marginBottom > 128 ?  '128px' : marginBottom + 'px';
is correct to my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

brownie.style.fontSize = (256 - value/4 >= 192) ? (256 - value/4 + 'px') : '192px';

brownie.style.marginBottom = (value >= 128) ? (value + 'px') : '128px';

You can also store the values in a temporary variable first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).